A consequente of the Implicit Function Theorem in $\mathbb{R}^2$
For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $f_n : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_n(0,0) = 0$ and $\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial t}(0,0) \neq 0$. By Implicit Function Theorem there exists $\delta_n > 0$ and a  $C^1$ function $T_n : (-\delta_n,\delta_n) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $T_n(0) = 0$ and $f_n(s, T_n(s)) = 0$ for all $s \in (-\delta_n, \delta_n)$.
By hypothesis, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ I know that $\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial t}(0,0) \neq 0$. However, if we assume that $\delta_n \to 0$, is it possible to prove that $\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial t}(0,0) \to 0$ if $n \to \infty$? Is it a continuity consequence?
Edit: My question appeared from the following problem: Assume there exists $M> 0$ such that $\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial t}(0,0) > M$ for all $n$.  In this case, the sequence $\delta_n$ should be bounded from below ?

You have to put some restriction on $\delta_n$, that it is as large as possible or similar. For now I can just take a smaller $\delta_n$ and keep the functions $f_n$ the same.

I am assuming that $\delta_n \to 0$, we can use this fact.

@LucasLinhares As mentioned by spinosarus, $\delta_n$ is not defined uniquely. You can always chose to have $\delta_n \to 0$ if you don’t add something to specify $\delta_n$.

Now I understand. I just wrote an edit which makes more clear my doubt.

What does $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ means for a function $f:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$?

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(s,t) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(s,t+h) - f(s,t)}{h}$

My question here is has to do with this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5016213/doubt-in-a-step-of-obtaining-the-critical-point-of-a-functional-using-ekelands

So it's the partial derivative w.r.t. the second variable. How are users in the forum supposed to know that? Edit your question to fix it (users shouldn't have to read the comments to understand  your question).

For $f_n(s,t)=-1-n^2s^2t+t$ we have $T_n(s)=(1-n^2s^2)^{-1}$ and ${\partial f_n\over \partial t}(0,0)=1.$ However $\delta_n=n^{-1}.$
